How to print values from **Kwargs
So I'm making a text-based game that requires me to have multiple doors leading to other rooms and multiple items. I can use the *args operator to list doors just fine, but when I use **kwargs to list the items, it gives me a dictionary, and when I print the values, it gives me (for example) 'dict_list['magazine']'. How do I rid myself of the 'dict_list' and print the value?
I tried using .values(), as stated above
Here's a snippet:
class Room:
    def __init__(self, desc, *doors, **items):
        self.desc=desc
        self.doors=doors
        self.items=items

    def describe_room(self):
        print(f"\ndescription = {self.desc}")
        print(f"\ndoors = {self.doors}")
        print(f"\nThe room contains: {self.items.values()}")
        for item in self.items.values():
            inventory.append(item)
        print(f"\nInventory: {inventory}")

Living_Room=Room('it stinks in here', 'door to bathroom', 'door to fireplace', item_1='gun', item_2='magazine')

but that didn't work. I'm stumped. I tried using the .join() method. I wanted to join the values instead of printing them directly to see if that would do anything, but that doesnt. Here is a snippet of what I tried:
def describe_room(self):
    print(f"\ndescription = {self.desc}")
    print(f"\ndoors = {self.doors}")
    items_list = self.items.values()
    print(f"\nThe room contains: {self.join(items_list)}")
    for item in self.items.values():
        inventory.append(item)
    print(f"\nInventory: {inventory}")

Living_Room=Room('it stinks in here', 'door to bathroom', 'door to fireplace', item_1='gun', item_2='magazine')

please go easy on me lol, im very new to programming. Any and all asnwers would be appreciated

Use ', '.join(self.items.values()) instead.

I can't see dict unpacking or kwargs in any of the methods you listed. Where exactly are the kwargs you're trying to print from?

When you pass any type to print(), Python tries to get the type to provide its representation or its value as a string.
For a string, that's trivial - to print 'Hello world!', it just prints the characters Hello world!, although even then there are some rules, like you have in your code (where you use \n to indicate a newline).
For complex types, like a dictionary or a list, things are not as straightforward. Often, there is no exact 'string value', but there is the representation of the variable, as it would appear in Python code. For example:
xs = [1, 2, 3]
print(xs)  # prints "[1, 2, 3]" (without the quotes)
d = {1: "one", 2: "two"}
print(d)  # prints "{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}"

Note that it seems like printing a variable just gets you what was defined in Python code - but that's not true. If you look closely at how the dictionary d is printed, you'll note that single quotes were printed around the string values, because that's the default in Python, even though they were defined with double quotes (which is an alternative that also works).
Often, you want more control over how something is printed, instead of just relying on how a standard class happens to present itself. For example, you may want to print the list as just a series of numbers separated by a comma and space, with no brackets:
xs = [1, 2, 3]
print(', '.join(xs))  # hoping for "1, 2, 3"

This causes an error, because .join only works to join together a bunch of strings, and xs contains integers, so this would need to have the integers converted to strings explicitly (even though print() does this automatically when just printing a single integer):
xs = [1, 2, 3]
print(', '.join(map(str, xs)))  # actually prints "1, 2, 3"

In your case, what you're trying to join appear to be the values (without the keys) of some dictionary:
print(', '.join(self.items.values()))

However, it's unclear why you would want to pass these as a dictionary, instead of for example a list. It would be more helpful if you presented what you're trying to do, because your question may well be an example of the XY problem, that is the solution you're asking about is not the best solution to the underlying question.
Note: it's clear from the title that you're working with unrestricted keyword arguments, for which the parameter is typically called kwargs - but it's unclear why you would.

Thanks! Sorry I'm doing an assignment for computer science and the requirement is that we have to use a class, and by extension, args and kwargs in the class. Thank you! And sorry,  I forgot about my stack overflow post. Many thanks!

That's alright, if you think my answer answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark. If you don't, and no longer require an answer, consider deleting the question. Either way, it would no longer appear as unanswered to people looking for information or a question to answer.
